# If, Elif, Greater than, Less than Logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have multiple conditions for this game if a user reaches a certain amount of money, then the more money they steal if the other user is at their level.

I'm having an issue trying to figure out the logic. I've added comments asking questions but I just don't know if there's an easier way to approach this type of thing.

Do I start from a lower value when I start my if statements or should I start with my large values?

```
# do I need to put a check and money(message.author) < 500000 here?
if money(message.author) >= 20000 and money(user) < 20000: 
    do_thing1()
# do I need to put a check and money(user) < 500000 here?
elif money(message.author) < 20000 and money(user) >= 20000: 
    do_thing1()
# do I need to put a check money(message.author) and money(user) < 500000 here?
elif money(message.author) >= 20000 and money(user) >= 20000: 
    do_thing2()
# do I need to put a check and money(user) >= 20000 here?
elif money(message.author) >= 500000 and money(user) < 500000: 
    do_thing2()
# do I need to put a check and money(message.author) >= 20000 here?
elif money(message.author) < 500000 and money(user) >= 500000: 
    do_thing2()
elif money(message.author) >= 500000 and money (user) >= 500000: 
    do_thing3()
```

Comment: Looking at this more closely, I don't think I captured everything in my answer below. What *exactly* are the cases that you want to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't show what happens if *both* have less than 20000, or if *both* have more than 20000 but less than 500000. I will show where those are handled below.

```
if money(message.author) < 20000 and money(user) < 20000:
    do_thing0()  # both have < 20000. You didn't show this case.
elif money(message.author) < 20000 or money(user) < 20000:
    do_thing1()  # only one of them has < 20000
elif money(message.author) < 500000 and money(user) < 500000:
    do_thingX()  # both have >= 20000 but < 500000. You didn't show this case.
elif money(message.author) < 500000 or money(user) < 500000:
    do_thing2()  # both have >= 20000, only one of them has < 5000000
else:
    do_thing3()  # both have >= 500000
```

If you don't care about the cases where both have `< 20000` or both have `>= 20000 and < 500000`, then you can shorten this with exclusive ors:

```
elif money(message.author) < 20000 ^ money(user) < 20000:
    do_thing1()  # only one of them has < 20000
elif money(message.author) < 500000 ^ money(user) < 500000:
    do_thing2()  # both have >= 20000, only one of them has < 5000000
elif money(message.author) >= 500000 and money(user) >= 50000
    do_thing3()  # both have >= 500000
```

Note in the last case we need to be explicit, otherwise we'll catch *anything* that wasn't caught by our first two cases, and here I'm assuming you don't want to catch the case where both have less than 20000, for example.

Your code executes sequentially, so if you make it past one of the checks, that tells you something about the range you are in and you can adjust your logic accordingly.

For example, once you've made it to the `elif money(message.author) < 500000 and ...` check, you know that both `money(message.author) >= 20000` *and* `money(user) >= 20000` because you wouldn't have made it this far if that wasn't true.

Comment: Wow I guess I've just been overthinking this! Thanks so much for the fast reply, I'll try this out. My question is, if `money(message.author) > 20000 and money(user) < 20000` will it still call `elif money(message.author) < 20000 or money(user) < 20000:` ?

Comment: Shouldn't the do_thing1` case use xor `^` instead of `or`?

Comment: I don't think I had caught everything in my original post. I have updated it and added comments showing what each case catches. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh I just noticed the use of `or` in your answer. This eliminates the need for the two extra checks of `>= and <` and `< and >=`. Very good and thorough explanation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Do I need to put a check and money(message.author) < 500000 here?
> ```

Yes, you do, otherwise some of your cases will include others, e.g., if `money(message.author) == 500001` and `money(user) == 1`, you probably want `dothing2` to happen, but instead it will trigger `dothing1`.

You could use comparison chaining for those, e.g. instead of

```
if money(message.author) >= 20000 and money(message.author) < 500000 and money(user) < 20000: 
    dothing1
```

you could use the much shorter

```
if 20000 <= money(message.author) < 500000 and money(user) < 20000: 
    dothing1
```

Also, defining two temporary variables `ma = money(message.author)` and `mu = money(user)` might greatly help readability. Given the large number of `if` and `elif` statements, you might even define `ma1 = ma < 20000`, `ma2 = 20000 <= ma < 500000`, etc., but this might be overkill. You could also define variables `low = 20000` and `high = 500000`, preventing typos (is that four zeros or five?) and making it easier to change that in future.

```
if low <= ma < high and mu < low: 
    do_thing1()
elif ma < low and low <= mu < high: 
    do_thing1()
elif low <= ma and low <= mu: 
    do_thing2()
elif high <= ma and mu < high: 
    do_thing2()
elif ma < high and high <= mu: 
    do_thing2()
elif high <= ma and high <= mu: 
    do_thing3()
```

Comment: Wow this answer is good too. The main objective isn't the sum of `user + message.author` money, but to check if they both have a certain amount in the JSON file, then it will take money from `user` and add it into `message.author`. The code is pretty long so I tried to simply my question a little. If they both reach over a certain amount of money, the amount stolen is raised (by a declared variable when it's added into the json file) but if one person is at that certain level, and the other one isn't, I want it to only take the lower amount.